# How to distinguish manual scroll from programatically triggered one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, addeventlistener

I need a way to distinguish manual scroll from programmatically called el.scrollIntoView()
I tried to google it and they have some suggestion like to use wheel event and similar, but that is not solving the problem as it is not covering every scroll type ( for example it is not including manual scroll when you drag and drop scrollBar)

Here is the code for better context:

```
const [autoScrollEnabled, setAutoScrollEnabled] = useState(true);
const autoScrollDelay: any = useRef(null);


useAutoScroll(autoScrollEnabled);

const pauseAutoScroll = () => {
    if (autoScrollEnabled) {
      setAutoScrollEnabled(false);
    }
    clearTimeout(autoScrollDelay.current);
    autoScrollDelay.current = setTimeout(() => {
      setAutoScrollEnabled(true);
    }, 3000);
  };

  const onScroll = useCallback(
    event => {
      if (isPlaying) {
        pauseAutoScroll();
      }
    },
    [isPlaying, autoScrollEnabled],
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const list = document.querySelector(
      "[data-testid='@panel-layout/content']",
    );

    list?.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);

    return () => {
      list?.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
      clearTimeout(autoScrollDelay?.current);
    };
  }, [onScroll]);
```

Autoscroll hook

```
export const useAutoScroll = (enabled = true) => {

  const currentTime = useSelector(state => state.timeline.currentTime);
  const isPlaying = useSelector(state => state.timeline.isPlaying);

  const shouldAutoScroll = currentTime && enabled && isPlaying;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (shouldAutoScroll) {
       const currElUuid = calculateUuid();
       const el = document.querySelector(`[data-uuid="${currElUuid}"]`);
       if (el) {
          el.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'end' });
        }
    }
  }, [currentTime, enabled, isPlaying, subs, lastHighlightedUuid]);
};
```

And then in custom hook I am calling
`el.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'end' });`
,  which triggers the same scroll listener as the manual one, and all the time calls my `pauseAutoScroll()` method which I need to prevent from being called by scrollIntoView.

Would really appreciate your help

Comment: That seems like a back-to-front solution. You might instead ask for better solutions to your problem in general, such as refactoring the upstream code.

Comment: My solution would be set `autoScrollEnabled` to false until scrollIntoView has finished, the set it to true again. However you already have this variable, and you are already calling `pauseAutoScroll`. Judging from the names it sounds like you have 99% of what you need for this already in place. Can you explain what `pauseAutoScroll` is doing? And what automatic scrolling is taking place?

Comment: @ChrisG I edited question and added missing methods/hooks
I have logic for autoscrolling on some text and its rows, and then if you manually scroll I want to pauseAutoscrolling, and that is why I am listening `scroll` event, but scrollIntoView is also the one who is listening to it, so it feels like circular dependency.

Comment: @isherwood, I explained it a little bit better. Do you have maybe suggestion how I could change the upstream code?

Comment: yeah, `Event.isTrusted` isn't suitable here.

Comment: I trying to process what you're doing here and I'm pretty certain the best solution here is a [FSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). Basically, when you call scrollIntoView, you need to set a flag/state variable (like `setManualScroll(true)`) and check that before pausing the scrolling.

Comment: I tried something similar, to update useRef value and read it's `current` property, but it doesn't solve the problem, as the scroll event is tricky one and is registered too often, so can't rely on that. But can try with regular useState variable